# Sitefinity - Remove translations column in backend screen

Tags: sitefinity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Equ05.png)

Anyone can help me remote translations column in module builder sitefinity?

Comment: I assume you want to "remove" the column? If so, why don't you just disable the translations module?

Comment: Because I don't want translate this module. Only English for this module and I don't want my client open another language

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a module to have translations, then just remove "Make localizable" checkbox ***from all fields*** for this module.

And Sitefinity will automatically remove this column from backend.

[image]